# Is it possible to store cache events in Apache Ignite?

Tags: ignite, audit, audit-logging

As we can persist cache data in Apache Ignite by enabling persistanceEnabled property. Is there a similar way we can store audit events as well, i.e. when we restart ignite server, all cache events must also be retained as they are currently lost on a server restart.

I am open to any other better approach for auditing via Ignite. I basically want to store all audit operations (especially INSERT,UPDATE) which we can review(fetch) later in the future?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement your own [`EventStorageSpi`](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/eventstorage/EventStorageSpi.html).